# Return .mp3 from a separate server as audio file, not raw text

Tags: php, binary, audio-streaming, http-proxy

I am developing a very humble web app which routes all the requests to get an audio file toward a third party server, where the actual files are stored.
In order to do this, I am using the following statement in my PHP code:

```
echo file_get_contents('https://3rdpartyserver.com/' . $filename);
```

By testing it, it seems to work properly only for text files. While trying to get an .mp3 file, instead, its content as text is actually displayed (instead of the default HTML audio player, which is displayed if I connect directly to the third party server).

I have also tried to add some headers to the response:

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
```

But the resulting behavior is still not what I am looking for.

Might you please suggest me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Why not redirect to the target URL instead, and cut your bandwidth utilization in half?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Type` to `audio/mpeg`, then write the file to the output buffer.

```
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);

readfile('https://3rdpartyserver.com/' . $filename);
exit;
```

Comment: I modified the headers and still an error is returned (Chrome shows ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE). Maybe should I add some further headers? In addition, this code is injected in the 404 error file (since the files actually are not in the current server). Might this affect the result of the request (I see that status code is still 404, even if the request is computed correctly for text files)?

Comment: Issue resolved: it was related to the status code 404.